# Find a module location in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I want to find where is module not in the admin panel, but in raw files in joomla. I tried wingrep and so on but didn't find anything what expected. It is module that creates left menu, in index.php it is:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left_menu" style="xhtml"/>`

When page loads it converts it to a menu with list items and anchors inside. I want to customize it but can't do it in the way i want from admin panel.

What is the best way to localize where the function lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modules folder in jooma**

You can find the modules files in `modules` from the module name in the  backend you should find in which folder are the files you are looking for.

**Override a module**

[Here](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) you can find even a guide how to change the layout of a module from the template.

This tutorial is more to change how it looks like not the functionalities.